# Converting Bitmap Image to SourceImage

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, video-streaming

I'm using some code to show live video from a camera.

In Windows Form (C#) the code worked fine, but in WPF application i getting an error in :

```
Bitmap img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
Image.Source = img;
```

the error was : connot convert System.Drawing.Bitmap to System.Wondows.Media.ImageSource. So i converted the Bitmap image using this code:

```
public ImageSource imageSourceForImageControl(Bitmap BitmapImage)
{
ImageSourceConverter SourceImage = new ImageSourceConverter();
return (ImageSource)SourceImage.ConvertFrom(BitmapImage);
}
```

Then i got a System.NullReferenceException

Any idea what should i do??

PS : Im a Newbie with C# applications

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/621920/How-to-convert-Bitmap-to-ImageSource

Answer (score 0):

I was using this for quite some time, try this.

```
public ImageSource imageSourceForImageControl(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    using(MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
        memory.Position = 0;
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        return (ImageSource)bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having an 'System.InvalidOperationException' with this

Comment: Are you getting the error inside this method?

Comment: No there is no error inside this method.
the exception is comming from this scope
image.Source =  imageSourceForImageControl(img);